# Reading 1625 burial record from East Quantoxhead, Somerset, England?

Tags: england, palaeography, burial-records, somerset

The image below is the burial record of a woman that I think I can prove to be my 10th great grandmother, Margarett Dayworthie, who married Peter Blackwell on 30 Nov 1587 at East Quantoxhead, Somerset, England, but I am struggling to read a few words from it.

[image]

A transcription of it has been indexed by Ancestry.com in its *Somerset, England, Church of England Baptisms, Marriages, and Burials, 1531-1812* as:

```
Name    Margaret Blackwell
Event Type  Burial
Burial Date 9 Nov 1625
Burial Place    East Quantoxhead, Somerset, England
Phillimore Ecclesiastical Parish Map    9786
Spouse  Peter Blackwell
```

My reading of the image is:

```
[two words] the [word probably being ninth] day of November
was buried Margarett [word which seems close to Blackwell] the
wife of Peter Blackwell
```

I am fairly confident that the "word which seems close to Blackwell" really is Blackwell but is anybody able to make out what letters are written in the first, second and fourth words prior to "day of November"?

---

The same two starting words seem to be at the beginning of each burial record in this register.  See below for some more examples:

[image]

Comment: Handwriting tutorial http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/palaeography/ has other documents if you want to compare w/docs from the same period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entries begin "Item uppon the...". *Item* is a Latin word meaning "also", commonly found in British parish registers and documents such as inventories where entries are written in list. On its etymology, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/item) states:

> The word started as Latin *item* for "also", "in the same manner", and
>   got its present English meaning from a misunderstanding of its usage
>   in lists, where the first entry would begin "In primis" (Latin for
>   "firstly"), and the other entries with "Item" (Latin for "also"), in
>   former times when most learned people in England knew Latin.

The same word is abbreviated variously at the beginning of other entries you have posted.

The date is certainly the "ninthe". Compare each letter to other instances in the document.

I would interpret the surname as "Blackewell".

Generally, the resource for palaeography in this period that I reference most frequently when there is a word I am having trouble reading is [English Handwriting 1500-1700](http://www.english.cam.ac.uk/ceres/ehoc/), particularly the [Alphabets](http://www.english.cam.ac.uk/ceres/ehoc/alphabets.html) page. There are also other useful resources listed on the [tag info](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tags/palaeography/info) page for [palaeography](/questions/tagged/palaeography).